# Gradient of a rational Bezier curve

Tags: calculus, parametric, bezier-curve

I'd appreciate help working out the gradient of a rational Bezier curve $C = (\,x(t) \,, \,C_y(t) \,)$. I know that the gradient $g$ of a the parametric curve is

$$
g(t) = \left( \frac{dy(t)}{dt} \right) \left( \frac{dx(t)}{dt} \right)^{-1}
$$

And from equation (10) of the paper [Derivatives of rational Bezier curves](http://www.mn.uio.no/math/english/people/aca/michaelf/papers/bez.pdf) (by M. S. Floater) I know that

$$
\frac{dx(t)}{dt} = \frac{ \omega_{0,n-1}(t) \; \omega_{1,n-1}(t) }{\omega_{0,n}^2}( \; x_{1,n-1}(t) \; - \; x_{0,n-1}(t) \; )
$$

and

$$
\frac{dy(t)}{dt} = \frac{ \omega_{0,n-1}(t) \; \omega_{1,n-1}(t) }{\omega_{0,n}^2}( \; y_{1,n-1}(t) \; - \; y_{0,n-1}(t) \; )
$$

where $x_{i,j}$ and $y_{i,j}$ are the coordinates of the control points of curve, obtained during recursive evaluation (I've taken some liberties with the notations used in the [paper](http://www.mn.uio.no/math/english/people/aca/michaelf/papers/bez.pdf)), from which I reason that

$$
g(t) = \frac{ y_{1,n-1}(t) \; - \; y_{0,n-1}(t) }{x_{1,n-1}(t) \; - \; x_{0,n-1}(t) }
$$

So that for example if given a degree 3 rational Bezier curve with control points $(0,0),(3,0)(6,5)(9,5)$ and corresponding weights $(1, 3 , 3 , 1)$,

$$
g(t) = \frac{40t^2 - 30t}{18t^2 - 9}
$$

The (discontinuity) in plot of this equation (shown below) suggests that the formula for g(t) is incorrect, as Bezier curves do not have discontinuities.

[image]

**Edit**

The parametric equation(s?) of the example rational Bezier curve above is (are?)

$$
x(t) = \frac{5t^3+45(1-t)t^2}{t^3+9(1-t)t^2+9(1-t)^2t+(1-t)^3}
$$

$$
y(t) = \frac{9t^3+54(1-t)t^2+27(1-t)^2t}{t^3+9(1-t)t^2+9(1-t)^2t+(1-t)^3}
$$

and the plot (below) looks about right

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I haven't checked all your algebra, but your general approach looks correct.

The flaw in your reasoning is your statement that "Bezier curves don't have discontinuities". A (2D) Bezier curve is a mapping $t \mapsto (x(t), y(t)) = \mathbf{C}(t)$. It's true that this mapping is infinitely differentiable -- all its derivatives are continuous.

But this doesn't imply that the mapping $g(t) = y'(t)/x'(t)$ is continuously differentiable. In fact, $g(t)$ will have a discontinuity wherever $x'(t) = 0$ (i.e. wherever the curve has a vertical tangent).

It looks like there is some mistake in your computation of $g(t)$. Your expression for $g(t)$ will go to infinity when $t= \sqrt2$, which suggests that the curve has a vertical tangent when $t= \sqrt2$. But your picture of the curve looks correct, and clearly there is no place where its tangent is vertical.

Another reason your formula for $g(t)$ must be wrong -- when $t=1$ it should give $g(1)=0$, and it doesn't.